# De-Referencing Record Elements

Tags: delphi, record, dereference

I have a Record being filled by a DLL written in C that has this structure:

```
 Thackrf_device_list = record
   serial_numbers: PPAnsiChar;
   usb_board_ids: ^hackrf_usb_board_id;
   usb_device_index: PInteger;
   devicecount: Integer;
   usb_devices: PPointer;
   usb_devicecount: Integer;
  end;
```

The record seems to be filled correctly, because the returned integers 'devicecount' and 'usb_devicecoun't are as expected.
What I cannot figure out is how to de-reference the other elements.
What I need is cookbook or some good examples.
Any help

Comment: "What I need is cookbook or some good examples." Please visit this page and read it very carefully: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  Note item 4: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.* After asking 30+ questions here it is reasonable for us to expect you to know this without having to remind you.

Comment: Sorry about using the word 'Book'. I do need reminding now and again thank you very much.
 I still need help in dereferencing the record. Do you have any?

Comment: Perhaps you could consult a textbook or the documentation. Pointers are comprehensively documented.

Comment: @David: pointers are perhaps comprehensively documented, but I know  that many don't grok them immediately, or grok them at all. My own article explaining pointers as I see them got lots of thank-you messages from people who finally got them, despite the "comprehensive" documentation. Documentation is often very formal.

Comment: @SetiNet: take a look at my article [Addressing pointers](http://www.rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pointers.html). Quote: *"This article was written for everyone with problems understanding or using pointers. It discusses my working view on pointers in Delphi for Win32, which may not be entirely accurate in all aspects (for instance, memory for one program is not one big block, but for most practical purposes, it helps to pretend it is). This way, pointers are easiest to understand, in my opinion."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dereferencing pointers is quite simple. It does not matter if the pointer belongs to a record, a class or is just some variable. You dereference a pointer by adding the `^` operator right after the pointer's identifier.

For example:

```
var
  LDeviceList: Thackrf_device_list;
  LSomePAnsiChar: PAnsiChar;
  LSomeUsbBoardIDs: hackrf_usb_board_id;
  LSomeInteger: Integer;
  LSomePointer: Pointer;
begin
  // fill LDeviceList by the C-written DLL

  LSomePAnsiChar   := LDeviceList.serial_numbers^; // returns a pointer to the first char of a string containing the serials as 'serial_numbers' seems to be a pointer to a pointer (PAnsiChar)
  LSomeUsbBoardIDs := LDeviceList.usb_board_ids^; // gives you the record of type 'hackrf_usb_board_ids'
  LSomeInteger     := LDeviceList.usb_device_index^; // returns the device index as an integer value
  LSomePointer     := LDeviceList.usb_devices^; // returns a pointer as 'usb_devices' seems to be a pointer to a pointer
  // ...
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Dereferencing a pointer in Delphi is a simple matter of using the dereference operator.  When a pointer is dereferenced it yields a value of the type referenced by the pointer.  For an untyped pointer this means you need to typecast to tell the compiler what type is yielded by the dereferencing:

```
var
  intPtr: PInteger;
  charPtr: PChar;
  ptr: Pointer;
  int: Integer;
  char: Char;
begin
  // ..

  int  := intPtr^;   // read as: int := the int pointed to by intPtr
  char := charPtr^;  // read as: char := the char pointed to by charPtr

  // For untyped pointers you need to cast

  int  := Integer(ptr^);
  char := Char(ptr^);
end;
```

So if a pointer is a pointer to a pointer then dereferencing it yields that pointer, which can in turn then be dereferenced.

You can use this dereferencing pointer for variables and for members of classes and records (as in your example).  However, the compiler and the language also support *automatic* dereferencing where appropriate.

That is, if you have a pointer to some record type and wish to reference a specific member of *that* record, you can still use the dereference operator **or** you can leave the dereferencing operator out (the compiler will automatically dereference for you).

Using a simple **TPoint** record as an example:

```
type
  PPoint = ^TPoint;
  TPoint = record
    X, Y: Integer;
  end;

var
  pointPtr: PPoint;
  myX, myY: Integer;
begin
  //..

  myX := pointPtr^.X;
  myY := pointPtr^.Y;

  // or you can simply write:

  myX := pointPtr.X;
  myY := pointPtr.Y;
end;
```